# How To Store Custom Field Data in CartThrob Session

Tags: expressionengine, cartthrob

I have a "gift message" custom fields setup on the last page of my CartThrob checkout process. Here's my code sample:

```
{exp:cartthrob:checkout_form return="/checkout/billing/process"}
    <textarea id="gift_message" name="gift_message">
         {if gift_message}
              {gift_message}
         {/if}
    </textarea>
{/exp:cartthrob:checkout_form}
```

If the order is submitted and there's an error, the "gift message" data isn't retained. How can I force it to save to the CartThrob session?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With custom data, you have to prefix the names to save to the session:

ie. `<textarea id="gift_message" name="custom_data[gift_message]">` You may need to change the conditional to: `{if custom_data:gift_message}{custom_data:gift_message}{/if}`

Comment: You probably don't need the conditional. If `{custom_data:gift_message}` returns something - it will, if not - it'll just be blank anyway.

Comment: Oddly, this didn't work on my first test... but did on my second and third!